# Looping AngularJS $http calls - TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a script to populate my app database with Dummy Data as I am getting tired of manually adding users/friends/etc, I'm doing this by nesting AngularJS $http requests that speak to my app backend API/Rest service...

So far all is working well but now I need to loop async calls, like so... please note that this is the 3rd nested $http call

```
// 3. Create Auto Friend For that User
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) { // 6 is just a given number, it could be 1 or 100....
   ($http({method: 'POST', url: '/path/to/rest/friend', data: {"name":"Auto Friend " + i}})
      .then(function (response) {
         console.log("friend created");
         console.log(response);

      }, function () {
         console.log('Whoops...');
      }))(i); // THIS IS LINE 69
}
```

I'm currently getting the following error...

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at http://localhost:9000/assets/js/src/app/auth/controllers/AuthCtrl.js:69:40
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/assets/js/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:10549:81)
    at http://localhost:9000/assets/js/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:10635:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9000/assets/js/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:11528:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9000/assets/js/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:11373:31)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9000/assets/js/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:11634:24)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
    at done (http://localhost:9000/assets/js/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:7635:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:9000/assets/js/vendor/bower/angular/angular.js:7801:7)
```

I've made some slight amends to my code but nothing seems to work, I assume my approach is wrong rather than the code (but I could be wrong there). Has anyone got an idea or recomendation on how i can overcome this issue?

Comment: What's the purpose of wrapping the `$http` within ()?

Comment: To create a closure - if you don't, the value of i may have changed before the http get is actually performed.

Comment: Hi CodeHater, I was trying to freeze the value of i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I may have answered this myself, I didn't wrap the code in a `function`...

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) { // 6 is just a given number, it could be 1 or 100....
   (function(i){
     http({method: 'POST', url: '/path/to/rest/friend', data: {"name":"Auto Friend " + i}})
      .then(function (response) {
         console.log("friend created");
         console.log(response);

      }, function () {
         console.log('Whoops...');
         });
      })(i);
}
```

Next time I will open my eyes before posting, thanks for the comments...